# Is chemistry finally seeing the end of the Haber-Bosch nitrogen fixation process?

Tags: electrochemistry, nitrogen, industrial-chemistry

**Do recent developments in alternatives to the Haber process for nitrogen fixation have good prospect of replacing it?**

Some recent headlines have suggested that the century-old Haber process for turning nitrogen into ammonia might be seeing some competition. For example [this report](https://newatlas.com/energy/green-ammonia-phosphonium-production/#:%7E:text=Scientists%20at%20Australia%27s%20Monash%20University,percent%20of%20global%20greenhouse%20emissions.) claims:

> Scientists at Australia's Monash University claim to have made a critical breakthrough in green ammonia production that could displace the extremely dirty Haber-Bosch process, with the potential to eliminate nearly two percent of global greenhouse emissions.

is this a reasonable prospect given the chemistry involved? Given what we know about the chemistry and economics of Haber or its alternatives, is replacing the process something chemists can reasonably hope for?

Comment: I would not say the process is more dirty than production of car Li-ion batteries, powered by fossil fuel power plants.

Comment: @Poutnik How dirty it is in comparison to other processes isn't really the issue. I think chemists can agree it is hugely energy and capital intensive and that any alternative that reduced either of those inputs would be relatively better.

Comment: As someone who worked on nitrogen fixation via electrochemical methods: It is unlikely to replace Haber-Bosch in the near and even further future. The Haber-Bosch process is very well optimized, scales well and the infrastructure is established. Currently electrochemical production methods have higher CAPEX and OPEX for most applications and even the better established field of CO2RR is nowhere close to large scale commercial applications. It has however potential in decentralized production, most ammonia comes from just a few production plants. So in the middle of the outback maybe?

Comment: @Noah I'd like to hear more detail not least because headline writers have tended to make big claims on opex and capex implications of the electrochemical methods (presumably without any analysis).

Comment: This article is clickbait. HB is just equilibrium chemistry, the thermodynamics will never change. Since those guys came up with this, there were a century of chemists trying to replace this with something more efficient. Is nice that people are still trying, but I don't see it happening in my lifetime.

Answer (score 13):

As with many proposed green processes, this method relies on electricity to replace direct use of fossil fuels as an energy source. The electricity must itself come from some primary energy source, so we need green (or at least greener) electricity to work as advertised.

In addition, the Haber-Bosch process may also be made green(er), as hydrogen has also been the object of green production. If green hydrogen production on a large scale were to become successful, then it could also be used as the fuel to sustain the reaction temperature as well as the reducing agent in the H-B process.

A secondary issue is that lithium has limited availability. Magnesium is also a good nitride former, and is much more abundant; so the electrolytic method would be more competitive if it were carried out with magnesium as the discharge anode. A magnesium/magnesium nitride-based method is proposed by [Hu et al.](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.xcrp.2021.100425).

**Reference**

1. Yang Hu, George Z. Chen, Lin Zhuang, Zhiyong Wang, Xianbo Jin (2021). "Indirect electrosynthesis of ammonia from nitrogen and water by a magnesium chloride cycle at atmospheric pressure".
   *Cell Reports Physical Science*,
   Volume 2, Issue 5,100425,
   ISSN 2666-3864,
   https://doi.org/10.1016/j.xcrp.2021.100425.